# Cant login to gmail using cookies

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies, webdriver, gmail

I'm using selenium webdriver to login to my google account and then saving the cookies and then opening a second webdriver to use those cookies to sign in. I can access my Google Drive and all my other accounts EXCEPT my gmail for some reason. After I set the cookies and I try to access my gmail it presents a login page.

```
#####login and save cookies 

w = webdriver.Chrome()
w.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin")

email = w.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'email']")
email.send_keys('USERNAME@gmail.com')
email.send_keys(Keys. ENTER)

password = w.find_element_by_xpath("""//input[@type="password"]""")
password.send_keys('PASSWORD')
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
next_click = w.find_element_by_css_selector("[class = 'RveJvd snByac']").click()

w.get('https://accounts.google.com/')

pickle.dump(w.get_cookies() , open("google_cookies.pkl","wb")) #saving cookies

##### opening second driver
second_driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
second_driver.get("https://www.google.com")

cookies = pickle.load(open("google_cookies.pkl", "rb")) #using the cookies
for cookie in cookies:
    if 'expiry' in cookie:
        cookie['expiry'] = int(cookie['expiry'])
    second_driver.add_cookie(cookie)
second_driver.get("https://myaccount.google.com/") #after the cookies are set and I try to access my gmail it presents a login page again.
second_driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!! Just assign `secure` as `False` and `domain` as `google.com`.

```
for cookie in cookies:
    cookie_copy=cookie
    cookie_copy["secure"]=False
    cookie_copy["domain"]="google.com"
    driver.add_cookie(cookie_copy)
```